# In the figure ,Prove that $AG=GH=CH$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.$E$ and $F$ are midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$.
>   Prove that diagonal $AC$ is trisected.

Till now i have proved that $\triangle BAE\cong \triangle DCF\\
\implies \angle AEB\cong \angle CFD\\
\implies \angle AEG\cong \angle CFH\\
\implies \triangle AEG\cong \triangle CFH...........(\text{ASA congruency} )\\
\implies AG\cong \angle CH\\
$

I m looking for a hint to move further.

Comment: Would a proof using vectors work for you?

Comment: $\quad$No sorry , only allowed to use college geometry.

Comment: E is miles off the midpoint of AD (A needs to go left)

Comment: @ jon :Figure not drawn upto scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\triangle BCG$ and $\triangle EAG$ are similar and $BC=2FC=2EA$, we have $CG=2AG$, that is $GH+HC=2AG$. Repeat the argument, we can have that $AH=2HC$, that is $AG+GH=2HC$. Summarize them, $AC=CG+AG=3AG$ and also $AC=AH+HC=3HC$, thus $AG=HC$, and then $GH=HC$, hence, $AC$ is trisected.

Answer (score 1):

As $|BF|=|FC|$, We have $|GH|=|HC|$ and as $|AE|=|ED|$, we have $|AG|=|GH|$ . So We are done.

Comment: i need to show reason why $GH$=$HC$.

Comment: @TAKITAKI: As $\dfrac{|BF|}{|FC|}=\dfrac{|GH|}{|HC|}$

Comment: @TAKITAKI: If it is not clear for you, check this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)